# How to redirect to a specific view in a controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm getting started with Zend Framework and MVC more widely and i can't manage to redirect the user in case he has entered something in the form...

```
<?php

class adresseController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

  public function init() {
    global $config;

    $protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"], 0, 5)) == 'https' ? "https://" : "http://";
    $this->view->url = $protocol . $config->app->url;
  }

    public function adresseAction() {
    //Si la méthode isPost() de l'objet de requête renvoie true, alors le formulaire a été envoyé.
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
      //récupération des données
      $prenom = $form->getValue('prenom');
      if($prenom == "arnaud")
      {
        $this->_helper->redirector("inscription/index");
      }
  }

}
}
?>
```

Field in question in my HTML form:

```
  <div><input type="text" name="prenom" value="" title="Pr&#233;nom *" class="small error"/>
```

inscription/index is the name of the view i want to be redirected to.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to URL then use this :

```
$this->_redirect("/inscription/index");
```

And if you want to redirect to controller then you are already using that :

```
$this->_helper->redirector('action', 'controller');
```